# Angular protractor Failed: script timeout after redirect from third party login

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I am using protractor `v5.3.2` and I want login using nonangular page.

```
login() {
    const loginButton: ElementFinder = element(by.id('authentication-login-button'));
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    loginButton.click(); // redirect to third party login page
    // login page
    const kcLogin: ElementFinder = element(by.id('username'));
    const kcPass: ElementFinder = element(by.id('password'));
    const kcLoginButton: ElementFinder = element(by.id('kc-login'));

    kcLogin.sendKeys('[login]');
    kcPass.sendKeys('[password]');

    // on successful login page will redirect back to my angular page
    kcLoginButton.click();

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    browser.get('/home');

}
```

After successful login, none of my testing suites are being run and after few seconds I get an error

```
Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
```

However if I comment last 2 lines, tests run as I expect but I guess that `waitForAngularEnabled` should be enabled.

```
// ...
// on successful login page will redirect back to my angular page
kcLoginButton.click();

// browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
// browser.get('/home');
```

Is there any way how to make this with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` or it is ok that `waitForAngularEnabled` is set to false ?

Comment: hi did you solve this? I am also using Keycloak and I have the same problem

Comment: nope ... i just left `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`